# Add Twitter Posting functionality to Octopress blog

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-oauth, octopress

I followed the blog post here: [How To Tweet New Blog Posts in Octopress](http://fusion94.org/blog/2013/01/13/howto-tweet-new-posts-in-octopress/) and I think everything went pretty smoothly.

When I tried to blog something, this is the error I get when making a new post by running `rake new_post`

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `configure' for Twitter:module
/root/danijelj.com/Rakefile:31:in `<top (required)="">'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

When I review line 31 in that file, this is what it says:

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
```

That line comes directly from the post mentioned. Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Comment: Which gem are you using?  And is it ready for Ruby 2.0.0?

Comment: I installed Twitter 5.0.0

`gem install twitter`
`gem "twitter", "~> 5.0.0"`

http://rubygems.org/gems/twitter

Comment: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/search?q=configure&ref=cmdform and it seems that there is no configure method as is reported by your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that blog is out of date.  According to the documentation, they show this form to do what was shown in the blog.

Configuration works just like Twitter::REST::Client

```
client = Twitter::Streaming::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY"
  config.consumer_secret     = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET"
  config.access_token        = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
  config.access_token_secret = "YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET"
end
```

Searching the repository in a cursory manner, I get this result: github.com/sferik/twitter/search?q=configure&ref=cmdform

It seems that there is no configure method as is reported by your error.

Comment: <del>How did you find that result? Where would I go to find answers like this in future?</del>

I found where you found that info. I will test it soon!

Comment: I just looked through the repository, and the documentation, and had that failed, I would have grabbed the gem and unpackaged it and used something like `grep` or `awk` or `pry` to go through the code.  The source code itself often has the best answers.